# Amended a git commit and force-pushed it, but the old commit is still on the local and remote repos

Tags: git

I made a commit, then pushed it.  A few minutes later, I amended that commit's message and did `git push origin -f`.  Despite doing `git gc` on my end and running housecleaning on the remote end, the non-amended commit is still there.  How do I get rid of it?

Comment: `git gc` doesn’t change the remote. What’s housecleaning?

Comment: I was asking why ````git gc```` didn't get rid of the commit on the local end.  Housecleaning (well, housekeeping) is this:  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/housekeeping.html

Comment: You can use `git gc --prune=all` for that (but see what `git help gc` has to say about it).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you need to do that? (Dangling commits end up being garbage collected eventually.)

Comment: I was wondering why mention of the commit was still showing up at gitlab.